# i add the google-services.json in the right postion but not work ,alss i have a error google-services.json is missing

Tags: android, json, flutter

i add the google-services.json in the right postion but not work ,alss i have a error google-services.json is missing , i use flutter & android studeio

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':path_provider_android:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.
> Searched Location:
> C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider_android-2.0.11\android\src\debug\google-services.json
> C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider_android-2.0.11\android\src\google-services.json
> C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider_android-2.0.11\android\google-services.json

how i can solove it .
thanks

Comment: where have you added the file?

Comment: hi @irsvmb  android /app/ google-services.json under the build.gradle

Comment: run flutter clean and try again. Is the file correctly spelled?

Comment: i use the flutter clean no change

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the `android` folder as a project, then run Gradle sync on it. It should work then. Path: `project_name/android/app/google-services.json`

Comment: thank you but this not work too.